# Query and process REST API using extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have created a web application and deployed it in my tomcat. The API is a GET request and URL is: http://mymachine.home.net:8080/test.app-1.0/test/json which returns an output as:

{"details":[{"name":"tim","age":"13"},{"name":"jim","age":"15"}]}

I want to write a very simple extjs application that will call the URL and print the response (or write the response to a file). Can someone help me with this? I tried the examples mentioned at many places, but my URL is never hit from the extjs application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to put the Ext code you've tried if you want to get an answer. The log of the AJAX request will probably be needed too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved. A few things that I added / changed were:

1. I included ext-all.js in the index.html page.
2. The response returned from the web application was changed as:
   someCallback({"summary":[{"hits":9118,"avg":13,"min":1,"max":1448,"errors":0,"date":"This period"},{"hits":1,"avg":1,"min":1,"max":1,"errors":0,"date":"Average"}]});
3. The callback name (someCallback) is sent as query parameter to the web application. The URI was changed to http://mymachine.home.net:8080/test.app-1.0/test/json?callback=someCallback

The response has to be wrapped around a string like ‘someCallback(…)’, else the Extjs code will not be able to parse it.